# Is it possible to execute UNION query to get data from 2 data tables with java hibernate

Tags: java, hibernate

This is the example i am provide following my my exact case

I want data from two db tables into one list with UNION or any other query in java hibernate

I tried the following
Entity for table 1 this is my first data table that have 2 columns :

```
@Entity
@Table(name="TABLE")
public class Table  {

        @Id
        @Column(name="NAME")
        private String name;

        @Column(name="PHONE")
        private String phoneNumber;


        public String getPhoneNumber() {
                return phoneNumber;
        }

        public void setPhoneNumber(String phone) {
                this.phoneNumber = phone;
        }
   }
```

This Entity for my second db table that have same columns as first db table.

```
    @Entity
    @Table(name="TABLE_2")
    public class Table2  {
    
            @Id
            @Column(name="NAME")
            private String name;
    
            @Column(name="PHONE")
            private String phoneNumber;
    
    
            public String getPhoneNumber() {
                    return phoneNumber;
            }
    
            public void setPhoneNumber(String phone) {
                    this.phoneNumber = phone;
            }
   }
```

My Query :

```
select a from Table a union select a from Table2 a;
```

My  code to get data and store into list with new object

```
    public ArrayList<DTO> getUsers(){

            ArrayList<DTO> flist = new ArrayList<DTO>();
            Query q = null;
            String query = null;
            query = "select a from Table a UNION  select a from Table2 a";
            try{
                    AppEntityManager appEntMgr = AppEntityManager.getAppEntityManager();
                    appEntMgr.startTransaction();
                    
                    q = appEntMgr.createQuery(query);
                    q.setFirstResult(0);
                    q.setMaxResults(10);
                    
                    List<Object[]> list = q.getResultList();
                    
                    DTO dto = null;

                    for (Object[] folderType: list) {
                            dto.setName((String)folderType[0]);
                            dto.setPhoneNumber((String)folderType[1]);
                            flist.add(dto);
                    }
           }catch (Exception e) {
                    log.error("Exception ::" + e);
           }
            return flist;
    }
```

Please help me if is it possible to get data from 2 DB table or Explain me

Answer (score 0):

It would be easiest if you use table per class inheritance:

```java
    @Entity
    @Inheritance(TABLE_PER_CLASS)
    public class TableBase {
    
            @Id
            @Column(name="NAME")
            private String name;
    
            @Column(name="PHONE")
            private String phoneNumber;
    
    
            public String getPhoneNumber() {
                    return phoneNumber;
            }
    
            public void setPhoneNumber(String phone) {
                    this.phoneNumber = phone;
            }
    }

    @Entity
    @Table(name="TABLE_1")
    public class Table1 extends TableBase {}

    @Entity
    @Table(name="TABLE_2")
    public class Table2 extends TableBase {}
```

then you can use the following code:

```java
    public List<TableBase> getUsers(){
        AppEntityManager appEntMgr = AppEntityManager.getAppEntityManager();
        appEntMgr.startTransaction();
        return (List<TableBase>) appEntMgr.createQuery("select e from TableBase e")
                    .setFirstResult(0)
                    .setMaxResults(10)
                    .getResultList();
    }
```

Comment: Hi am unable to pass 2 parameters to createQuery

Comment: I have no idea what `AppEntityManager` is, that's your own class. `javax.persistence.EntityManager` has a `createQuery(String query, Class resultType)` method. You can also remove the second parameter and do a cast.

Comment: if i pass only query am getting exception 
JDBCExceptionReporter:77 - SQL Error: 1146, SQLState: 42S02
02:42:14,522 ERROR JDBCExceptionReporter:78 - (conn:107546) Table 'r_db.TableBase' doesn't exist

Comment: I don't know what your `AppEntityManager` does. It's your own class. You'll have to debug that yourself. I can only tell you how Hibernate works.